# QT 5.10.1[Static mingw32] + MySQL. QMYSQL driver not loaded

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Никак не получается подключить MySQL к qt, использую Mingw32 со статической линковкой. Ошибка: 
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3.

При использовании Mingw32 с динамической линковкой(из-пакета) все отлично работает. Использую длл и lib из пакета MySQL Connector C.
P.S. Dll в папку с проектом кидать пробовал, во все-возможные папки sqldrivers тоже.

Comment: Сразу вопрос: а есть ли у вас статическая библиотека, которую вы собираетесь линковать? *"Dll в папку с проектом кидать пробовал, во все-возможные папки sqldrivers тоже"* намекает, что ее нет (и да, в папку со своим проектом кидать ничего не надо в любом случае).

Comment: Похоже, что ее нет(

Comment: Я брал все библиотеки из пакета MySQL Connector C. Где брать статические?

Comment: Их нужносамому собрать вот ссылка на иструкцию https://habr.com/sandbox/95171/

Comment: Собрал, ничего не работает. По папкам типа: C:\Qt\5.10.1\mingw53_32_static\plugins\sqldrivers\ все файлы раскидывал.